# How do I re-use the same image payload in several pages without repeating it?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf to generate a report that contains a logo from a svg vector image.
My goal is to efficiently re-use the same image payload over and over in the report, not storing the logo as if it was a different image on each page.
Right now, with the current data, the report generates 32 pages. The file size considerably increases with new pages being added. This seems to be due to the logo being repeated on every page.
I don't have tools to analyze what is inside the pdf but I can see from other reports that are generated by other applications, that the file size of pdfs containing repeated images peaks at 1 page and then on each consecutive page, the size increases very slightly, indicating that the first logo is efficiently re-used.

How can I achieve that using tcpdf?

If in my report, I place the logo only in page 1 and omit it in pages 2 - 32, still outputting all the text data, the file size is greatly reduced, just as in the examples that I mentioned before. This indicates that the svg data is repeated on every page.

From the example 009 in tcpdf's site documentation, I've tried loading the image from file and also tried using a "data stream" (this is encoding the svg in base64 and instead of referencing the image from a file, you use the text-based base64 variable content as a stream that contains the image payload).
I thought that using the data stream would take care of it, but it didn't.

Is there a way to reference the same image over and over in tcpdf?